# Why does this tsvector update use so much space?

Tags: postgresql, update, disk-space

This is my table structure:

```
  Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |               Default                | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('tbl_disk_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 inserttime  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()                                | plain    |              | 
 buildid     | text                     |           | not null |                                      | extended |              | 
 app_version | text                     |           | not null |                                      | extended |              | 
 device      | text                     |           | not null |                                      | extended |              | 
 device_api  | text                     |           | not null |                                      | extended |              | 
 userid      | text                     |           | not null |                                      | extended |              | 
 path        | text                     |           | not null |                                      | extended |              | 
 size        | numeric                  |           | not null |                                      | main     |              | 
 type        | integer                  |           | not null |                                      | plain    |              | 
 root        | integer                  |           | not null |                                      | plain    |              | 
 status      | integer                  |           | not null | 0                                    | plain    |              |
```

I used this query to check the size of the table:

```
SELECT  relname AS "relation",
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    AND C.relkind <> 'i'                                                   
    AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
    AND relname like 'tbl_disk%'
  ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
  LIMIT 20;
```

The result:

```
       relation        | total_size 
-----------------------+------------
 tbl_disk_20180830     | 90 MB
 tbl_disk_20180831     | 32 MB
```

Now I add a new column `document` with type `tsvector`:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_disk ADD "document" tsvector;
```

and update the data:

```
UPDATE tbl_disk 
SET document = array_to_tsvector(ARRAY[split_part(path,'/',2),split_part(path,'/',6)]);
```

```
path data like : /data/user/0/com.abc.abc/database/olala.db
```

I just need two tokens 'data' and 'database' , that is why I split data.

After successfully updating, the size approximately doubles:

```
       relation        | total_size 
-----------------------+------------
 tbl_disk_20180830     | 175 MB
 tbl_disk_20180831     | 61 MB
```

The data :

```
                          path                          |      document      
--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------
 /data/user/0/com.abc.abc/lib/libabcqlite.so          | 'data' 'lib'
 /data/user/0/com.abc.abc/files/ddinfo2               | 'data' 'files'
 /data/user/0/com.abc.abc/lib/libabcsqlite.so         | 'data' 'lib'
 /data/user/0/com.abc.abc/lib/libabcsqlite.so         | 'data' 'lib'
 /data/user/0/com.abc.abc/shaders/b32                 | 'data' 'shaders'
```

You can see the size of `tbl_disk_20180830` increases from 90MB to 175MB.

I don't know why it needs such a lot of space to save two tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Databases cannot simply overwrite data "in place".  If they did, they wouldn't be able to have atomicity or isolation, and probably not much concurrency and durability either.

When you do a bulk update of every row in a table, in PostgreSQL, the resulting table has a copy of both the old data and the new data. You can rid of the copy of the old data by running `VACUUM FULL <table name>`.  Or you can just do a regular VACUUM, but if you do that it will not shrink the amount of space it takes up, it will just mark the space as being re-usable for future work on that table.

Comment: I tried to run VACUUM FULL tbl_disk but the size of tbl_disk_20180830 still 175MB .

Comment: @lethanh  If you are using partitioning by inheritance, you have to VACUUM FULL each child table by name.  Only with declarative partitioning (new in v10) will VACUUM FULL <parent_name> automatically operate on the children too.

Comment: My postgres version when check by query :  select version();  PostgreSQL 10.4

Comment: @lethanh  Version 10 offers both kinds of partitioning, declarative and inheritance.  Just because you are on 10.4 doesn't mean you are using declarative partitioning.

Comment: I checked and it's declarative.